# How to listen to Pandora music streaming outside United States? (e.g., in Canada)

Tags: pandora

I used to use Pandora's free online streaming music service, and I liked the way I could "thumbs up" or "thumbs down" songs to indicate my preferences in music, and explore related artists.  I bought *many* CDs after being introduced to new artists via Pandora.  However, some years ago, Pandora shut down access to Canadians.  (Boo!)

I was in the U.S. recently and was able to log in to my old account from the hotel room. I realized I miss Pandora quite a bit.  What's the easiest way to work around the restrictions that Pandora put in place?  I *promise* to support new artists I like and discovered via Pandora.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, what you want to do is proxy your requests through a server in the US.
The best way to do this is probably to sign up at [TunnelBroker](http://tunnelbroker.com/) and set it up on your computer as a VPN.

You can find instructions on how to do this on [Windows 7](http://www.tunnelbroker.net/help/windows7-vpn.php) and [Mac OS X](http://www.tunnelbroker.net/help/osx-vpn.php).

Comment: what about private vpn > Hotspot Shield app ?

Answer (score 7):

Now there's an even better tweak to make Pandora work outside US. All you have to do is install a Firefox (or Chrome) addon and there you go. No ads, no proxy tools and also blazing speeds.

> 1. If you are on Firefox, install the [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) extension developed by EFF and restart the browser.
> 2. If you are on Google Chrome, install the [HTTPS Enforcer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/beaholcfmnpbabojbldnhlikfmnjmoma) extension. Then click the extension’s icon in the Chrome address bar and set the status to enable.
> 3. Now open the [Pandora website](https://www.pandora.com/) in your browser and you should be able to use Pandora just like any other user inside the United States.
>
> The music will stream as long as the HTTPS extension is enabled in your browser. Also, if you are on Firefox, the default settings of the extension are good enough to enjoy Pandora.

Source: [Digital Inspiration](http://www.labnol.org/internet/access-pandora-music-anywhere/20976/).
Original source: [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/comments/qia65/lpt_how_to_access_pandora_anywhere_outside_usa/).

Comment: I just tested this from Canada, and it works. Easier than a proxy, but it looks like a loophole Pandora is likely to close at some point. But, hopefully this access will last a while.

Comment: As of June 14,2012 this doesn't work in Canada (Pandora specifically is indicated in the plugin as "broken")

Answer (score 2):

Proxies have a tendency to be slow and can be traced. For Pandora and Hulu from Canada I use jumpto.com. They have a secure browser that can be located in the US and it streams HD video just fine. I am on a Mac but the software only works on PC. So I use VMware to set up a PC partition on the Mac.

http://www.jumpto.com

Answer (score 1):

Over the last few months I've used [CryptIP](http://www.cryptip.com) and haven't had any problems so far. I'm using their VPN package for country restricted sites as Netflix, Pandora or Hulu or to bypass ISP Blocks as recently upcoming for thepiratebay etc.

I'm especially suggesting you them caused by their fast and nice support.